# NULL safe way of averaging values in two columns in a snowflake table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for a NULL safe way of averaging two columns in a Snowflake Table. I can use

```
select col1, col2, (col1+col2)/2 AS averaged_columns FROM tablename
```

but this doesn't work where there are NULL values in either of the col1 or col2 or both.

Comment: `coalesce(col1, 0)`  returns 0 if col1 is null.

Comment: What's the expected result if both col1 and col2 are null?

Comment: @jarlh, if both are null, then the expected value is NULL

Comment: And if col1 = 2 and col2 is null, do you want average as 2 or 1?

Comment: @jarlh if only one of the column is null, then the average should be the value from the other column. In your example it will be 2

Answer (score 3):

You can. use a `case` expression:

```
select col1, col2,
       (case when col1 is null then col2
             when col2 is null then col1
             else (col1 + col2) / 2
        end)
from t;
```

You can simplify this to the more inscrutable:

```
select coalesce((col1 + col2) / 2, col1, col2)
```

Note:  This assumes you want to *ignore* `NULL` values, not treat them as `0`.  If you want to treat them as `0`, use `coalesce()`:

```
select (coalesce(col1, 0) + coalesce(col2, 0)) / 2
```

A lateral join version should also work:

```
select t.*, a.average
from t cross join lateral
     (select avg(col) as average
      from (values (t.col1), (t.col2)) v(col)
     ) a
```

Comment: That is what all but the second to last queries here do.

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed too fast and I wasn't sure you'd even had the chance to see the last comment.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this! So just to check, could I do this for 4 columns? and if one was NULL it would divide by three?

Comment: @ClintonSorrel . . . Yes, you can generalize these to more columns.

Answer (score 0):

For null values in columns, have to convert the null values to 0. So check the below query

```sql
select col1, col2, 
(ISNULL(col1,0) + ISNULL(col2,0))/2 AS averaged_columns FROM tablename
```

Comment: Cast will not convert null to 0.

Comment: isnull can help in this

Comment: I'd recommend the standard compliant `COALESCE()`, https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2, (nvl(col1,0)+nvl(col2,0))/2
```

Comment: Can you offer an explanation of what the `nvl()` function does to help future readers with this question better understand this approach, and why it's preferred over the original code? Also, why is this preferred over `isnull()` or `coalesce()` as proposed in the other answers? Take a look at the explanations offered by other contributors—and especially that from [@Gordon-linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64487762/3025856)—as a good example of how to explain the code.